# getting error in creating the use user in the firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var vasu = rootRef("https://<my app>.firebaseio.com")
rootRef.createUser({
  email    : "swamy1234@gmail.com",
  password : "swamy1234"
}, function(error, userData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error creating user:", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
  }
});
```

iam getting error while iam runing this in my browser

```
error : Uncaught TypeError: rootRef is not a function
    at (index):771
(anonymous) @ (index):771
```

please suggest me a correct code

Comment: createUser is not a valid function

Comment: then how can i create a new user

Comment: and i also want to give reset password also for the user

Comment: what you really want? save user data in firestore or resgister new user?

Comment: [Authenticate with Firebase using Password-Based Accounts using Javascript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)

Answer (score 1):

Sign in a user with an email address and password use the following code

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword({
      email    : "swamy1234@gmail.com",
      password : "swamy1234"
    }).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
let newTransactionRef = rootRef.child('user').push()
// here user is your database ref in which you may want to insert a new user data
newTransactionRef.set('user').push({
      email    : "swamy1234@gmail.com",
      password : "swamy1234"
    }).then(function (userData) {
    // successfully created
    console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
}).catch(function(error){
  //error
  console.log("Error creating user:", error);
})
```

Comment: how can we manage a user account in fire base like reset password

Comment: so you need password reseting code, right? Did you used firebase-ui for auth or custom auth?

Comment: yes , i known the code how to add new user into fire base